# Set two prices per product for one store

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to set different prices for two customers.

If customer is commercial, than price should be $10.00.
If customer is government, than price should be $5.00.

How can I set this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two groups, put the customers there in and define group prices for both groups.

But be careful, it only works if the standard price is higher than $10

Comment: Yes that's great..
See My Standard Price is = Commercial price

now some time it happen that Government price is lower than standard price or Commercial Price.

than it will not displaying...

Answer (score 0):

Which Magento version are you running ? With the latest versions you can simple create a `customer group` (customer tab in backend) and than assign a `group price` in the product > price tab for each group.

Comment: I am using magento 1.7.2 

i have create two group but Government customer price is lower than standard price.